# Inline Markdown code blocks are not highlighted

Tags: pandoc

Whenever I want to `highlight` something in Markdown I use backticks (`). But when I try to convert the text:

[image: Markdown source]

with following command:

```sh
pandoc -f markdown -t pdf test.md -o test.pdf
```

I get this in resulting pdf:

[image: pdf output]

Is there a way to make it being highlighted like in other editors - with a box around that has somewhat different background color?

Example of what I would like to see in pdf output:
https://dillinger.io/
[image: Right way of highlighting]

Answer (score 1):

You can define colors for inline code blocks in latex:

```latex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bgcolor}{HTML}{ffcccb}
\definecolor{tcolor}{HTML}{c7254e}
\let\oldtexttt\texttt

\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
  \textcolor{tcolor}{\colorbox{bgcolor}{\oldtexttt{#1}}}
}
```

And add as a header:

```sh
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf -H head.tex
```